# Supress blank subreport produces blank space

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a main report with 4 grops(CR 2008). The page header content is repeated on each page. I placed the sub report in group footer 1. If the group foote 2 content flows till the end of margin and the subreport produces a blank space. Even i have set the sub report format as supress blank report and i even supressed the section if blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Firstly try to place the content of the subreport in a list bound to
  your data even if it's only one record. If there is no data, the list
  will not be rendered and will not use any space.
- Secondly check if the subreport extend the **horizontal** extend of
  the parent report (by reducing the width of the subreport). If so,
  there will always be a blank space in the main report, no matter what data you support for the subreport.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

use this formula When u suppress:

"IsNull({Necessary.DetailField}) or ({Necessary.DetailField}=" ")"